# need help to create a procedure that will return an object type which contains objects

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to create a oracle procedure that will return an object as output for some input . The returned object needs to be a nested object containing other objects.
example :

```
create or replace type DEMO_TYPE as object (ID number,RESPONSE_TXT VARCHAR2(1000));

create or replace type DEMO_LIST IS TABLE OF DEMO_TYPE;

create or replace type DEMO_MASTER AS Object(
demos DEMO_LIST
);

create table demo as (ID number,RESPONSE_TXT VARCHAR2(1000));
```

i want to create a procedure which will take id as input and return an object(say DEMO_MASTER ) which will contain all the rows of table demo say with same id, as objects(say DEMO_TYPE ).
I am using oracle 11g.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Procedure:

```
create or replace procedure find_demos(i_id in number, o_demo out demo_master) is
  v_demo_list   demo_list;
  v_demo_master demo_master := demo_master(null);
begin
  select demo_type(id, response_txt)
    bulk collect into v_demo_list
    from demo
    where id = i_id;

  v_demo_master.demos := v_demo_list;
  o_demo := v_demo_master;
end;
```

Test:

```
declare 
  d demo_master;
begin
  find_demos(2, d);
  dbms_output.put_line(d.demos(1).response_txt);
  dbms_output.put_line(d.demos(2).response_txt);
end;
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e34734c8562f125dcec13c40bcd77551)</sup>**